# How to see through an opaque mask?

Tags: optics

I have a face mask that I'm planning on making, a cosplay of Wrench from Watchdogs 2. Not satisfied with existing ones, I want to go for a more realistic one.

That being said, this requires that I make the entire part of the mask covering the eyes opaque. I'd also like to be able to look around with my eyes instead of moving my entire head around to view detail. Thid is also critical to the function of the mask. Basically high FOV covering my entire range of vision.

How might I implement this? I've thought about using stripped down VR goggles with a camera, mirrors to bounce light around from another point on the mask, or pinholes in the mask with lenses to allow you to see through them. (If that's possible, I'm not well acquainted with lenses.)

Answer (score 4):

Just a lot of pinholes (without lenses) will be enough.

With a high enough density Your eyes and brain will be able to compensate the lack of complete vision pretty dang well. It'll be darker and you shouldn't go driving while wearing it but you'll be able to see enough to enjoy a party.

One method could be to stretch a piece of thin black fabric over a frame. The weave will have a lot of hole for the light to come in.

Comment: This won't work as the front of the mask needs to be solid with minimal holes. I'm going to put a dot matrix LED display in the front, so there won't be a lot of room to drill holes.

Comment: it doesn't need to be solid, just look solid. You take a black T-shirt and stretch it in front of your eyes You'll be able to see through it. Then a bent coatwire to act as support.

Comment: You're not understanding. Imagine I have a solid block of concrete strapped to my face and I need to see through it. Stretching a shirt over that won't let me see through it. I have a solid board of LEDs strapped to my face, essentially.